# Modify text of a label created by code in iOS

Tags: ios, label, iboutlet

If I create a label programmatically, then how I can create the outlet to access his text property?
Thank you...

Answer (score 3):

You don't create an outlet -- that's only for hooking things up in IB. Instead, you create a property, and you use that to refer to your label. So in the .h file where you create your label, have something like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *myLabel;
```

When you create your label:

```
self.myLabel = [UILabel alloc] init .....
```

Then when you need to get the text property:

```
self.myLabel.text = @"New Text";
```